# Why is the probability of two elements $y_i$, $y_j$ being compared equal to $2/(j - i + 1)$ in random quicksort?

Tags: probability

Random quicksort is the quicksort where the pivot is chosen at random.  Let $y_1, y_2, ..., y_n$ be the elements in their final position in the sorted list.  (As opposed to $x_1, x_2, ..., x_n$ in the unsorted list.)

The question is what's the probability that some element $y_i$ will be compared to element $y_j$.  I can't answer that one.

I can answer some easier ones.

---

I can see the probability that element $y_1$ and element $y_n$ will be compared.  That only occurs if either one is chosen as a pivot as the first pivot chosen.  So that's $2/n$.

---

I can see the probability that element $y_i$ and $y_{i+1}$ will be compared.  That occurs eventually because the tendency for these two elements is go together in the same sublist.  This implies eventually they'll have to be compared because either one will be a pivot while both are in the same sublist.  So the probability of them being compared is 1.

---

Comment: Are you assuming that all the $y_i$ are distinct?

Comment: A very nice discussion of this problem, under the assumption that all the $y_i$ are different is given in section 3.4.2 of [these notes.](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~avrim/451f11/lectures/lect0906.pdf)

Comment: I think I must assume so, but I was not particularly with that in mind.  If I don't assume so, does the argument have a flaw?  Thank you!  (Thanks for the promising notes.)

Comment: IIRC you do have to assume distinctness.  Certainly, if they aren't distinct, you get lots of complications, especially since quicksort doesn't preserve the order of equal elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elements $y_i$ and $y_j$ remain in the same sublist as long as you choose pivots that are on the same side of them (both less or both greater). There comes a one point in the algorithm at which you choose a pivot that's either between them or one of them. If it's between them, they will never be compared. If it's one of them, they will be compared. At this point, all $j-i+1$ of these elements are candidates for the pivot, and they all have the same probability of being chosen. That's two favourable outcomes out of $j-i+1$ equiprobable outcomes, for a probability of $2/(j-i+1)$.

Comment: ``Elements $y_i$ and $y_j$ remain in the same sublist as long as you choose pivots that are on the same side of them (both less or both greater).''  That's correct.  However if they end up on the same sublist, this means they will be compared down the recursion that follows.  So I'm having trouble not saying that this probability is 1.  Where am I going wrong here?  Thank you!

Comment: @J They'll never get compared if a pivot is chosen between them.  They're compared if one of them is chosen; they're not compared if an element between them is chosen; if some other element is chosen, the decision is deferred to another level.  Any time the decision is actually made, the probability of success is $2/(j-i+1)$.

Comment: @saulspatz Quite right.  I see it now.  If we chose an element ouside the slice of size $j - i + 1$, then the random variable's value isn't determined and so further execution is required.  We're discussing when the value of the variable is determined and elements outside that slice are irrelevant to it, so they have no participation in the probability of $X_{i,j}$ being $1$ or $0$.  I got it.  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Reading your discussions inspired some thoughts for me. The case $y_1, y_n$ is easy as was pointed out by the original post. Let $T_{ij}$ be the event that $y_i<y_j$ are compared. We can try induction to prove the following: $$P(T_{ij})=\frac{2}{j-i+1},$$ irrespective of the total number of elements that are not within $\{y_i,\ldots,y_j\}$. The base case is when the list to be sorted is precisely $\{y_i,\ldots, y_j\}$. This is the same as the easy case, and the probability that $y_i$ and $y_j$ are compared is $\frac{2}{j-i+1}$. We now carry out an induction.

Suppose for any $0\leq k<m$, $P(T_{ij})=\frac{2}{j-i+1}$ among any $k+(j-i+1)$-list containing $\{y_i,\ldots, y_j\}$. To be more careful, each of the extra $k$ elements is either smaller than $y_i$ or bigger than $y_j$. To prove this for $k=m$, there are two possibilities that $y_i$ and $y_j$ are compared.

Case 1: An element other than $y_i\ldots, y_j$ is chosen. In this case, $\{y_i,\ldots,y_j\}$ is now within a shorter list to be sorted. Therefore, the probability that $y_i,y_j$ are compared is $$\frac{m}{m+j-i+1}\cdot\frac{2}{j-i+1}$$ by the induction hypothesis.

Case 2: One of $y_i,y_j$ is chosen. In this case, they are compared. The probability that either $y_i$ or $y_j$ is chosen is clearly $2/(m+j-i+1)$.

In sum, $$P(T_{ij})=\frac{m}{m+j-i+1}\cdot\frac{2}{j-i+1}+\frac{2}{m+j-i+1}=\frac{2}{j-i+1}.$$