# Why is the probability of two elements being compared equal to 2/(−+1) in random quicksort?

Tags: probability, computer-science, sorting

After reading [Why is the probability of two elements $y_i$, $y_j$ being compared equal to $2/(j - i + 1)$ in random quicksort?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2855077/why-is-the-probability-of-two-elements-y-i-y-j-being-compared-equal-to-2)

I am confused as to what $j-i+1$ means in the denominator.

Is it the same as saying $$\frac{2}{\text{the total number of elements}}?$$ Isn't that a more simple notation as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all explained in the question. We have an unsorted list $[x_1, x_2, ..., x_n]$ and then sort it to obtain $[y_1, y_2, ..., y_n]$. For two elements $y_i$ and $y_j$ of this sorted list with $i < j$, the probability that $y_i$ and $y_j$ are compared to each other at some point is $2/(j - i + 1)$. This obviously depends on which two elements are chosen, since $i$ and $j$ will be different for each one.

Comment: so j-i+1 is the total number of elements in the range of $y_i$ and $y_j$?

Comment: @mathguy Yes, that's right